# Interfaces, absolutly nothing other then pure virtual functions, or...?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, terminology

Every time I read about interfaces, it is mentioned that it hasn't have any data members or implementation what so ever.

But when I see code with interfaces, they have both.

```
class IInterface
{
public:
    IInterface(){}
    virtual ~IInterface(){}
    int getInt(){ return m_int; }
    virtual void Boo() = 0;
    int m_int;
};

class cInterface : public IInterface
{
public:
    virtual void    Boo()
                    {
                        printf( "defined in .cpp for readability\n" );
                    };
};

class cFoo : public cInterface
{
};
```

(Almost) never I see them in a source file but only headers.

How strictly is the term used and if the above isn't an interface, how is it called?

Does it reflect the usage of cInterface/cFoo when using it as IInterface*?

```
...
cFoo foo;
IInterface* object = &foo;
object->Boo();
...
```

Answer (score 6):

C++ has no formal definition of interface types in its language definition and no way to enforce writing a pure abstract class.  The concept however certainly exists in software engineering and goes back a long, long way.  Corba and COM are canonical examples.  The generic technique is called "interface based programming".  Another popular label is "design by contract".  Some C++ compilers have language extensions to support them, like __interface in MSVC.  It is still a plain class in every other way, the compiler just enforces purity.

One concrete example is using an interface to act as the definition of a proxy for an object that actually lives in another runtime environment.  Like on a machine half-way around the world.  The proxy, the local implementation of the interface, has methods that send the argument values on the wire.  The other end of the wire has a stub with the actual methods.  With the major advantage that the client code will need no changes whatsoever if the object is actually created locally, it still uses the same interface.  In other words, the implementation is invisible and doesn't affect the code.  The example you gave will *not* operate correctly in this scenario, the remote object will not have the correct value for the m_int member.  It is not an interface, just an abstract class.

Interfaces are especially important in languages that don't implement multiple inheritance.  MI is difficult due to the diamond problem.  But that's an *implementation* inheritance problem, there is no issue inheriting multiple interfaces.  The only minor problem such a language has to address is the ambiguity when two or more inherited interfaces have a method with the same name and signature.  But that can be easily solved by giving the language a way to specify which particular interface method is being implemented.  Like the "explicit interface implementation" syntax in C#.  Not sure what Java does.

Another aspect that's both practical and troublesome is that it is design tool, the "design by contract" angle.  If you work on a large project with a lot of developers then you tend to end up with a lot of interfaces.  They incorporate "this is what we *should* do", emitted by architects.  But without any "this is what I did", especially early in the project.  Real bugs are implemention bugs, rarely interface bugs.  An excellent tool to actually get multiple programmers to work concurrently.  But major suck to get the foundation of the project sound and locked-in so you can build on top.  Not the way that Bjarne works.

Comment: Accepted for the additional MI, dreaded diamonds and the design by contract which I researched a bit the last couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict definition of this term in C++. It's generally used *loosely* to mean a mostly abstract class: a class that defines a protocol for interaction rather than any kind of implementation. Since it's not a concept that's built in the language, people can be less strict about the definition, and data can sneak into an "interface" sometimes.

In some programming languages and systems, however -- Java being a prime example -- it's a language feature, and has a very formal meaning. In those environments the precise meaning is, of course, environment-specific, but generally it's about the same as discussed above. In Java, an *interface* is a sort of class with nothing but pure virtual functions and compile-time constant data members. Java lets a class *extend* just one other class, but a class can *implement* any number of interfaces.

Comment: Java is often mentioned. Do you know if the term is adopted from Java?

Comment: @JohnSmith the concept existed before java, but in java it is formalised and has a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

simply put, the 'interface' can be used to refer to methods and/or data -- concrete or abstract (e.g. `virtual`). a more basic definition of 'interface' is also often used to refer to what your implementation has access to (e.g. methods which are public are part of the public interface).

as Ernest noted, the definition you seem to have been expecting at some point is that of Java's, and Java's is much different because it means something very specific. Java's representation/definition of interface is similar to a pure abstract class in C++.

so, 'interface' is not equivalent to a pure abstract class in C++ -- it is a far more generic term, which can be used to refer to things like the object's *declared* methods (virtual or not) and base classes (while excluding the definitions of those methods). i say, even declared typedefs and constants could qualify as part of an object's interface (particularly in template metaprogramming); although i suspect that may be too far by some people's definitions (and really, an interface is not strictly defined in C++ -- so one person's definition may vary by the watering hole they frequented).

Comment: No, an interface cannot refer to abstract data.  That will take a major hardware revolution or hacking the language standard.  It is not completely alien, other languages support properties.  Which are actually methods, getter and setter.  Not a C++ feature, it is a fairly leaky abstraction.

Comment: @HansPassant you are clearly thinking of something different from me -- perhaps we should start with an explanation of how you find 'concrete data' acceptable, while 'abstract data' is objectionable. context: this question is tagged C++ - no other language.